# Assign value to observation based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a situation:

Let's consider two columns: visitor & id_user

Some 'visitor' have missing values on 'id_user, but other values not.

The thing is that same unique value of 'visitor' appears with both scenarios: having 'id_user' & having missing.

I want to fill the values for the cases where the same 'visitor' appears, with the 'id_user' value that sometimes appears for that particular case

I tried the following approach:
Make a dataframe with 'visitor' with NO-MISSINGS on 'id_user' (full_user)
Make a dataframe with 'visitor' with MISSINGS on 'id_user' (missing_user)

I iterate on both of them using zip:

```
for i,j in zip(full_user['visitor'], missing_user['visitor']:
        if i == j:
              missing_user['id_user'] = full_user['id_user']
```

But didn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Make a map between visitor and ID, then `id = visitor.map(mapping_to_id)`

Comment: `df['id_user']=df.groupby('visitor')['id_user'].ffill()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using dictionary while you zip the dataset.

```
dictionary = dict(zip(full_user['visitor'],missing_user['visitor'])

for i,j in dictionary :
        if i == j:
              missing_user['id_user'] = full_user['id_user']
```